# How to read POST request body in ServiceWorkerClient in Android

Tags: android, service-worker

We have created [ServiceWorkerClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ServiceWorkerClient)

(SWC) in Android which intercept the request coming from Service Worker. After intercepting the request, it modify the request and make network call using OkHttp client. We are good with GET request but there is issue with POST request. We are not able to read the body of POST request due to limitation of WebResourceRequest (class of request intercepted by SWC) APIs. WebResourceRequest do not provide any API which help us to read the body. We want to know how everyone is handling the POST request in Android . Is there any way we can read the body of POST request.